# Moodle keeps connecting to old database

Tags: sql-server, moodle

I am using moodle with mssql and I have 2 database instances in the same server. In the config, I tried changing as follow:

```
// $config.php 1st server
$dbhost = 'apa7\\dbname1';

// $config.php 2nd server
$dbhost = 'apa7\\dbname2';
```

But the application itself just keeps connecting to 1st server. Some weird encounter is I even tried removing entirely the dbhost and it still works without error:

```
// $config.php 1st server
$dbhost = '';

// $config.php 1st server
$dbhost = '';
```

Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light here.

Comment: Those variables matter nothing if the connection code doesn't use them. Look there :) And since even after removing the values you still connect to the old database fine that 100% means you are looking at the wrong config.

Comment: If that doesn't work, check that you're looking at the right config files

Comment: In config.php it should be `$CFG->dbhost = 'xxx';` not `$dbhost`

Comment: Yes I have tried echoing in the 2 config file echo 1; and echo 2; Both are running the right instances of files. And yes, I meant $CFG->dbhost = 'xxx'; Thanks, any other idea?

Comment: i have also drilled down to the main mssql_connect function and did an echo on the dbhost for both. Nothing seems to be wrong?

Comment: Just had a quick look at this - https://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP - it looks like the host is for the server rather than the database? The instance is stored in a conf file in the notes, I don't use sql server mysql so not sure how to connect